# Show arrow in menu

Tags: html, css

I am using this css code to show arrow icon in the menus. But I am not able to show arrows for all `ul`s. Can anyone correct the code?

```
ul.pureCssMenu span {
    display: block;
    background-image: url('/Images/arr_white.gif');
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

ul.pureCssMenu li:hover > a > span {
    background-image: url('/Images/arrv_white.gif');
}

ul.pureCssMenu a:hover span {
    background-image: url('/Images/arrv_white.gif');
}

ul.pureCssMenu ul span, ul.pureCssMenu a:hover table span {
    background-image: url('/Images/arr_white.gif');
}
```

`arr_white` is a horizontal image.

`arrv_white` is a vertical image.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: can you add it in jsfiddle?

Comment: Make sure image path are correct:)

Comment: Is the images folder in the same folder as the file the code is in?

Comment: Image path is correct and also Image folder is in the same folder where the codes are present.

Comment: noway to correct you without the HTML structure, just set a fiddle or codepen on line with fake image